# Set ngModel value of type file

Tags: javascript, angular

I am new in angular 6. I am creating a project using angular. I working with file uploads in angular 6. I am just updating the model value of file but getting the error.

Here is the code

```
<input type="file"  (change)="onFileChanged($event)" name="file" [(ngModel)]="info.file">
  ngOnInit() {
    this.info.file = this.profileImg // this contains the image path
  }



onFileChanged(event: any) {
    this.files = event.target.files;
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
      const file = event.target.files[0];

      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = e => this.profileImg = reader.result;

      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
  }
```

`this.profile` image is image path like [Image](http://jobreferral.in/equhub-server/public/uploads/short-sides-long-top-haircut-men-sample.jpg)

> ERROR DOMException: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string.

Comment: post some code instead of just one line.

Comment: question updated.......

Comment: Where are you declaring `profileImg` and when are you getting the error?

Comment: Also post code of this method: `onFileChanged($event)`

Comment: profileimg contains the image path ...

Comment: "which may only be programmatically set to the empty string." - that means you cannot set this property to any other value, than "" - empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `[(ngModel)]` from `input` and bind it in the `onFileChanged($event)` method.

```
<input type="file"  (change)="onFileChanged($event)" name="file"> 

onFileChanged(event: any) {
    this.files = event.target.files;
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
      const file = event.target.files[0];

      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = e => this.profileImg = reader.result;

      reader.readAsDataURL(file);

      this.info.file = this.profileImg
    }
}
```

See this issue: [Angular Issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6074)